# IEEE 802.15.6 channel

Tags: matlab

The following code is from the IEEE 802.15.6 standards for wireless body area networks. What is the number of channel realization? How can I choose its value? What is the relation between this value and the length of the input signal to be transmitted through the channel?

```
function [h, t, n_p] = uwb_hospban_chan_CM4(num_channels, body_direction)
% Function for getting channel realizations for UWB Hospital BAN channel CM4.
% Igor Dotlic (dotlic@nict.go.jp) March 2009.
% Input variables
% num_channels - number of channel realizations
% body_direction= 1: 0 deg, 2: 90 deg, 3: 180 deg, 4: 270 deg
% Output variables
% h - comlex multipath amplitude responses
% t - times of multipath arrivals (ns)
% n_p - number of paths for each channel realization
% Fixed model parameters
L_mean = 400; % mean number of arrival paths
lambda_inv= 0.50125; % mean time between arrivals (ns)
% Model parameters that depend on body direction
if body_direction == 1
Gamma = 44.6346; % (ns)
k_abs = 5.111739;
sigma = 7.30;
elseif body_direction == 2
Gamma = 54.2868; % (ns)
k_abs = 4.348859975;
sigma = 7.08;
elseif body_direction == 3
Gamma = 53.4186; % (ns)
k_abs = 3.638084447;
sigma = 7.03;
elseif body_direction == 4
Gamma = 83.9635; % (ns)
k_abs = 3.983472211;
sigma = 7.19;
end
% Calculating number of paths
n_p = poissrnd(L_mean, 1, num_channels);
for k_chan = 1:num_channels
n_p(k_chan) = max(n_p(k_chan), 1);
end
% Maximum number of paths
n_p_max = max(n_p);
% Allocating memory for channel realizations
h = zeros(n_p_max, num_channels);
t = zeros(n_p_max, num_channels);
% Calculating path arrival times
t_dif = exprnd(lambda_inv, num_channels, n_p_max-1);
for k_chan = 1:num_channels
t(2:n_p(k_chan),k_chan) = cumsum(t_dif(k_chan, 1:n_p(k_chan)-1));
end
% Calculating path levels
for k_chan = 1:num_channels
h(1,k_chan) = exp(i*rand*2*pi)*sqrt(10^(sigma*randn/10));
% Paths 2 onwards
for k_p = 2:n_p(k_chan)
h(k_p, k_chan) = exp(i*rand*2*pi)*...
sqrt(exp(-t(k_p,k_chan)/Gamma-k_abs)*10^(sigma*randn/10));
end
% Normalizing current PDP realization (may be commented out)
h(:,k_chan) = h(:,k_chan)/norm(h(:,k_chan));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the number of channel realization? How can I choose its value?

Looks like this affects the size of n_p you get. Its hard to suggest the value you want without knowing what exactly you are doing

> What is the relation between this value and the length of the input signal to be transmitted through the channel?

I think your input signal stays the same but if you have multiple channels then you send you input on all the channels.

Comment: I want to transmit a signal with 2048*1 size over this channel. Thus I need to obtain the impulse response h of the channel. I can not understand the meaning of (the number of channel realizations) to be able to decide the correct number. @Nirvedh Meshram

Comment: Well for 2048, I think using 2048 as number of channel realizations will give you the impulse response size you want. So I would recommend you try with that. I think it just means that you realized the behavior of the channel that many times to send the data